# Почему в ОС Debian файла dmesg.log нет, а в Ubuntu dmesg.log пустой?

Tags: ubuntu, debian

Почему в ОС Debian файла `dmesg.log` - нет, а в Ubuntu `dmesg.log` - пустой?

Comment: добро пожаловать в дивный новый мир [systemd/linux](https://askubuntu.com/q/859816/416190)